# Consulta sobre arreglo c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wcf

Estoy ejecutando procedimientos almacenados en mi proyecto `WCF C#`. De uno de mis SP recibo algo asi :

```
CeldaId
CeldaIndicadorCodigo
CeldaIndicadorTipoCodigo
```

Luego con el valor de `Celda Id` llamo a otro SP que me trae :

```
CeldaKeyCodigo
CeldaKeyValor
```

Desde el primer SP obtengo `CeldaId` y con ese valor obtengo los resultados del segundo SP.

Mi idea es desde mi servicio entregar un arreglo `JSON` más o menos con esta estructura

```
Celdas : [
     IndicadorCodigo : [
          {
              CeldaKeyCodigo : valor,
              CeldaKeyValor : valor
          },
          {
              CeldaKeyCodigo : valor,
              CeldaKeyValor : valor
          }
     ]
]
```

Vale decir, agrupar los valores de la consulta de mi segundo SP por el valor que tenga IndicadorCodigo.

La manera en que lo hice fue lo siguiente... Cree una clase llamada Celda con los campos anteriormente nombrados más una Lista de una clase llamada CeldaKeyVal con los cambos que me devuelve mi segundo SP.

```
public class Celda
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_indicador_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_indicador_tipo_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<CeldaKeyVal> valores_celda { get; set; }
}


public class CeldaKeyVal
{
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_valor { get; set; }
}
```

Luego de tener esta estructura, recorro asi los resultados :

```
public ListaCeldas GetCheckIn(int gsalid) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Db);
    List < Celda > celdas = new List < Celda > ();
    ListaCeldas listaCeldas = new ListaCeldas();
    try {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MBL_SEL_CELDAS", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gsalid", gsalid);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dtCelda = new DataTable();
        dtCelda.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        foreach(DataRow dr in dtCelda.Rows) {
            Celda celda = new Celda();
            celda.celda_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]);
            celda.celda_indicador_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorCodigo"]);
            celda.celda_indicador_tipo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorTipoCodigo"]);
            DataTable dtCeldasKey = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd_celdas_key = Helper.GetCeldaValoresKey(celda.celda_id);
            dtCeldasKey.Load(cmd_celdas_key.ExecuteReader());
            List < CeldaKeyVal > listaCeldaKey = new List < CeldaKeyVal > ();
            foreach(DataRow drCeldasKey in dtCeldasKey.Rows) {
                CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
                celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(drCeldasKey["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
                celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(drCeldasKey["CeldaKeyValue"]);
                listaCeldaKey.Add(celda_key_val);
            }
            celda.valores_celda = listaCeldaKey;
            celdas.Add(celda);
        }
        List < Celda > cl = celdas.OrderBy(c => c.celda_indicador_codigo).ToList();
        listaCeldas.celdas = cl;
        if (celdas.Count > 0) {
            listaCeldas.status = 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        listaCeldas.status = 0;
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return listaCeldas;
}
```

Esto funciona bien para mi pero no el orden que deseo, este es el JSON que recibo

```
{
  "GetCheckInResult": {
    "celdas": [
      {

        "celda_id": 1,
        "celda_indicador_codigo": "I001",
        "celda_indicador_tipo": "T01",
        "valores_celda": [
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
            "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
          },
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
            "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
          },
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
            "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
          },
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
            "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "celda_id": 4,
        "celda_indicador_codigo": "I002",
        "celda_indicador_tipo": "T03",
        "valores_celda": [
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
            "celda_key_valor": "codigo"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "celda_id": 5,
        "celda_indicador_codigo": "I002",
        "celda_indicador_tipo": "T03",
        "valores_celda": [
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
            "celda_key_valor": "ssddsds"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "celda_id": 3,
        "celda_indicador_codigo": "I003",
        "celda_indicador_tipo": "T02",
        "valores_celda": [
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
            "celda_key_valor": "sdadsa"
          },
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
            "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
          },
          {
            "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
            "celda_key_valor": "Texto 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

Sé que el error esta en mi estructura de las clases pero no se me ocurre como armarlas para conseguir el formato que quiero conseguir.

**LO QUE ESPERO**

Obtener un arreglo de celdas y sus valores ordenamos por `IndicadorCodigo`

Json esperado :

```
{
  "GetCheckInResult": {
    "celdas": [
         "T01" : [
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
              "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
              "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
              "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
              "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
            }
        ],
        "T02" : [
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
              "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
              "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
              "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
            },
            {
              "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
              "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: `public List<CeldaKeyVal> valores_celda { get; set; }` no debería estar dentro de una clase llamada tipo_codigo?

Comment: @PabloClaus Gracias por responder, la lista de Valores corresponde a una Celda (celda tiene mucho mas valores pero no los quise incluir porque no son relevantes para mi problema). Uno de los valores de Celda es IndicadorTipoCodigo.. y yo quiero agrupar en base a ese valor, los valores_celda, no se si me explico? Todos los valores corresponden a una Celda

Comment: Entiendo, pero parecería que el modelo no te hace fácil eso. Si fuera así: la clase Celda con una coleccion de tipo_código que a su vez tiene una colección de Valores_celda. ¿No sería más facil armar el objeto para luego transformarlo en json? (No sé si me explico...)

Comment: Eso estoy intentando!, como lo dije sabia que el error estaba en mi Modelo asi que intentare algo asi y te comento! @PabloClaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo asi (los nombres de los campos pueden cambiar acorde a tu gusto):

```
public class Celda
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_indicador_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<celda_indicador_tipo_codigo> { get; set; }

}

public class Celda_indicador_tipo_codigo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_indicador_tipo_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<CeldaKeyVal> valores_celda { get; set; }
}

public class CeldaKeyVal
{
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_valor { get; set; }
}
```